# How do I switch to another tab from current tab in the application programmatically using javascript and jquery on an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the tabs of jQuery UI

How do I switch to another tab from current tab in the application pro-grammatically using javascript and jquery on an event eg click of button.

Comment: You are not able to swith between tabs. You can only open links in a new tab or new window.

Comment: Make the question clear ?

Comment: Add some more details about the question and if possible share some of your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security concerns it is not possible. If by "tab" you mean a window and a popup window that opened up in a new tab.

```
window.opener.focus();
```

If you want to change to another  tab in a Jquery UI tab  by programmatically trigger the click event.

```js
$('#id_of_tab').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery UI Tabs use normal links to change the tabs. So easiest way to change tab is just clicking the link (with javascript/jquery). Say the link in your tab has an id like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1" id="tab-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2" id="tab-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3" id="tab-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
 </ul>
```

If you want to change to tab 2 you can use $('#tab-2').click();